# Calculating LOC from GIT commits

Tags: git

I'd like to calculate the number of lines of code I have modified over a period of time using git commits.

I used the below command

> git log --shortstat --author="xxx" --oneline --before="2018-04-31"
>   --after="2018-04-01" > commit_info.txt

But, this includes the empty lines and the comments as well.

Is there any other way to achieve what I expect?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out `gitstats`.

Comment: It's pretty hard to do this such that it's language agnostic. Filtering empty lines is easy enough, but comment syntax varies wildly. Btw, comments *are* source code. And sometimes crappy comments can waste a lot of time. Are you sure you want to filter them out for your LOC count? I've never bought the argument that comments and whitespace are not SLOC.